# matlab R2011a using solve() function with arrays instead of explicit values

Tags: matlab

i need help understanding what I'm doing wrong in the following MATLAB code:

> h=[6 6];
>
> zi=zeros(3);
>
> syms z
>
> z=solve('h(1)*zi(1)+z=0')
>
> z =
>
> -h(1)*zi(1)

as you can clearly understand I want the numeric values... not indexes...

any assistance is welcome

(I know this equation is actually 'z=0' but its just an example, not the real equation that needs solving...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the actual values in the string passed to `solve`:

```
z=solve([ num2str(h(1) * zi(1)) '+z=0'])
```

Comment: MATLAB output: `Error: Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket.`

Comment: @nrz: oops, sorry about that.  I fixed it now.